# How do I access a part of a string by by going backwards in a loop

Tags: python, string, loops, indexing

```
myList = []
myString = "this is my striNg 7"
```

Say I wanted to access "N" but I needed to do it by going backwards in a loop like this-

```
for i in myString:
    if i == "7":
       myList.append(i - 3 spaces)
```

How do I do this? I am struggling to find answers. Thanks

Edit- Im sorry im new to this and im not sure why it is not formatting this correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the "N" variable, or 3 characters before i by doing :

```
for i,str in enumerate(myString):
    if str == "7":
       myList.append(myString[i-3])
```

Enumerate will begin with i=0 and will add 1 to i each time the loop will continue, but I will advise you to add a condition to avoid a negative number, and an error to `myString[i-3]`, for instance:

```
for i,str in enumerate(myString):
    if (i > 2 and str == "7"):
       myList.append(myString[i-3])
```

Comment: This works thank you. I am a bit confused on what str is doing here though. Does putting str after "i" mean that when "i" goes through the loop it will go through as a string index counter instead of an integer? If this were the case though you would still be be able to say - if i == "7".

Comment: `enumerate` will enumerate your elements as you iterate over them, so `for i, str in enumerate(object)` will iterate on the elements (`str`) and on its enumerated indexes (`i`), so in your case `i` will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on while `str` is going to be 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', ecc

Comment: Great ! Glad that it solved your problem ;-) Don't forget to indicates the best answer that solved your problem by clicking on the validation button :-) You will have more details about it here --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm getting what you're asking here. If you want the highest index where the letter 'N' is present in your string, `str.rfind()` and `str.rindex()` are built exactly for this. The only difference between the two: `rfind` will return -1 in case of failure, `rindex` will raise `ValueError` instead. Or, if you want to loop backwards and append letters to a list starting from the end of the string:

```py
a_list = []
a_string = 'this is a string'

for i in range(len(a_string)-1, -1, -1) :
    a_list.append(a_string[i])

print(a_list)
['g', 'n', 'i', 'r', 't', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 'i', ' ', 's', 'i', 'h', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop on the string from last index to first and get that required element.

```js
myString = "this is my striNg 7";
for (i = myString.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  if(myString[i]=='N'){
  console.log('index of N is ' +i);
  }
}
```

Comment: @lupodellasleppa this is pure js